# How can I output and format the latest entry in an org file to the terminal?

Tags: bash, awk, emacs, terminal, org-mode

I keep daily notes using emacs and an org file which is structured as follows:

```
#+SEQ_TODO: TODO(t) IN_PROGRESS(p) BLOCKED(b) ON_HOLD(h) OPEN(o) QA(q) | DONE(d) CANCELLED(c)

* Notes <2019-04-19 Fri>
** To do:
*** Item 1
*** Item 2
* Notes <2019-04-18 Thu>
** To do:
*** Item 1
*** Item 2
*** Item 3
*** Item 4
etc.
```

I'd like to output the latest entry in the terminal (possibly through grep, cat, sed, or other means), so for example if I type `todo` in the terminal it would output:

```
* Notes <2019-04-19 Fri>
** To do:
*** Item 1
*** Item 2
```

I've tried things like `grep -A 5 -i "2019-04-18" ~/Documentes/notes.org` but don't want to have to manually specify how many lines to output (the list could be 2 lines or 10 lines). I've also experimented a bit with `sed` and trying to output between words but haven't had much luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming latest entry is always at the top:

```
$ awk '(c+=/^\* Notes/)>1{exit} c' file
* Notes <2019-04-19 Fri>
** To do:
*** Item 1
*** Item 2
```

For each line in `file`; if the line matches `^\* Notes`, increase `c` by 1; if `c` is greater than 1, exit; if `c` is greater than zero, print the line.

And, if a single asterisk at the beginning followed by a space only comes before `Notes` you can drop `Notes` from the regexp:

```
awk '(c+=/^\* /)>1{exit} c' file
```

Comment: That works, I guess one thing I forgot to mention is that my org file has the todo sequence statement at the top of the file (#+SEQ_TODO: TODO(t) IN_PROGRESS(p) BLOCKED(b) ON_HOLD(h) OPEN(o) QA(q) | DONE(d) CANCELLED(c)). How can I omit that line from the output? Thanks!

Edit: Updated my question to include sequence statement on top.